# Preventing page flicker when changing visibility of objects

Tags: asp.net, flicker

I have a button in my page, which when clicked makes visible (using back-end code) a Login Control. However, it doesn't just appear as I would wish, it actually flickers onto the page which is quite annoying.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using JavaScript instead???

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#myb").click(function () {
            $("#login").toggle();
        });
    });
</script>

<input type="button" id="myb" value="show/hide" />
<asp:Login runat="server" ID="login" DestinationPageUrl="~/Default.aspx" 
     .....
```

Comment: @Andre: the reason you got "flicker" is that you got a postback. Your browser had to redisplay the page entirely. This answer shows how to do it entirely on the client side, so, no postback and no "flicker".